# How do I hide a vertical scrollbar (without disabling it)?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I have a list but want to hide the scrollbar but still keep the functionality. If I put verticalScrollPolicy="off", this disables scrolling via the mousewheel on windows (100% of my users use windows). How can I hide the scrollbar visually but keep the ability to scroll via the keyboard as well as the mousewheel?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"    
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"     
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"  height="100%" width="100%">

<s:Group>
    <s:List id="listy" width="50%" height="100">
        <mx:ArrayCollection>
            <fx:String>Flash</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Director</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Dreamweaver</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>ColdFusion</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Flash</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Director</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Dreamweaver</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>ColdFusion</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Flash</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Director</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>Dreamweaver</fx:String> 
            <fx:String>ColdFusion</fx:String> 
        </mx:ArrayCollection>
    </s:List>

</s:Group>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just type:

```
<s:Scroller id="myScroller" verticalScrollBar="{new VScrollBar()}">
```

This code solve my problem=)

Answer (score 6):

I believe the way you'd want to do it to set a custom skin for the List, which then sets a custom skin for the Scroller component within it.  In the Scroller skin, you could set the scrollbar as visible=false.

Answer (score 2):

Ive been looking for a solution for this question , and I think it's a problem many people ancounter , so I decided to answer this question although its quite old.

The solution for your problem is real simple. You simply make a custom skin for the scroller and inside the scroller simply set the vertical scroller "alpha" property set to zero

```
<s:VScrollBar id="verticalScrollBar" visible="false" alpha="0"/>
```

Hope this will help someone

Comment: thanks! in my position this resolves the issue with the least amount of effort :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use verticalScrollPolicy="off" and create a listener for the mouse scroll event to trigger the scrolling when the mouse is hovering the list.

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide scrollbars but still have access to scrolling functionality, you need to create a custom skin and a css style.

1. Create a custom skin for the VScrollBar with the following settings:

   Host Component: spark.components.VScrollBar

   Select "Create as copy of:", and select "spark.skins.spark.VScrollBarSkin"
2. Edit the "SparkSkin" tag in your custom skin by adding "*minWidth="0" minHeight="0" width="0" height="0" alpha="0" visible="false" contentBackgroundAlpha="0"*"

   **Original**

   `<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
       xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" minWidth="15" minHeight="35" 
       alpha.disabled="0.5" alpha.inactive="0.5" >`

   **Customized**

   `<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
   xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" minWidth="0" minHeight="0" width="0" height="0" alpha="0" visible="false" contentBackgroundAlpha="0">`
3. Then edit your custom skin by adding "*alpha="0" visible="false" width="0"*" to each of the elements:

   **Original:**

   ```
   <s:Button id="track" top="16" bottom="15" height="54"
             focusEnabled="false" tabEnabled="false"
             skinClass="spark.skins.spark.VScrollBarTrackSkin" />

   <s:Button id="thumb" 
             focusEnabled="false" visible.inactive="false" tabEnabled="false"
             skinClass="spark.skins.spark.VScrollBarThumbSkin" />

   <s:Button id="decrementButton" top="0" enabled.inactive="false"
             focusEnabled="false" tabEnabled="false"
             skinClass="spark.skins.spark.ScrollBarUpButtonSkin" />

   <s:Button id="incrementButton" bottom="0" enabled.inactive="false"
             focusEnabled="false" tabEnabled="false"
             skinClass="spark.skins.spark.ScrollBarDownButtonSkin" />
   ```

   **Customized:**

   ```
   <s:Button id="track" top="16" bottom="15" height="54" alpha="0" visible="false" width="0"
             focusEnabled="false" tabEnabled="false"
             skinClass="spark.skins.spark.VScrollBarTrackSkin" />

   <s:Button id="thumb"  alpha="0" visible="false" width="0"
             focusEnabled="false" visible.inactive="false" tabEnabled="false"
             skinClass="spark.skins.spark.VScrollBarThumbSkin" />

   <s:Button id="decrementButton" top="0" enabled.inactive="false" alpha="0" visible="false" width="0"
             focusEnabled="false" tabEnabled="false"
             skinClass="spark.skins.spark.ScrollBarUpButtonSkin" />

   <s:Button id="incrementButton" bottom="0" enabled.inactive="false" alpha="0" visible="false" width="0"
             focusEnabled="false" tabEnabled="false"
             skinClass="spark.skins.spark.ScrollBarDownButtonSkin" />
   ```
4. Add a style to your css (change "assets.skins" to the location of your skin file in your project):

   s|List s|VScrollBar {
       skinClass:              ClassReference("assets.skins.VerticalScrollBarHidden");
   }

   This style will only apply to List components, so the scroll bar will still be visible for other components. If you want to remove scrollbars altogether, remove "s|List" from the style definition.
5. Finally add the stylesheet to your application mxml component (replace "assets/css/Styles.css" with the location of your stylesheet):

   `<fx:Style source="assets/css/Styles.css"/>`